# How to get the data usage details of map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I know that [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) API provides the details of data usage while sending or receiving data from android application. I want to know the data usage detail from map. How can I get it ? Suppose I open an application, load the map and perform some activity like zoom in, zoom, out, drag map. During this activities google map is going to consume some data usage. How can I find out that how much data usage is done by the my application's map ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, , I found answer my self, Using [TrafficStats](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) class I can get the data usage details for a particular application as follows,

```
int uid = android.os.Process.myUid(); 
long receivedBytes = ts.getUidRxBytes(uid);
long sendBytes = ts.getUidTxBytes(uid);
```

Operating System it self preserves these details based on the process's uid.